# Substring of XML element in same line as select

Tags: xml, xslt, substring, padding

I am new to XSLT so bear with me.

I wrote a simple template for getting values from an XML file and displaying them in a simple text format.

I have this line here which works:

```
"Supplier Invoice Payments Descriptor: <xsl:value-of select="wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/@wd:Descriptor"/>"
```

The descriptor is an attribute as such:
`<Suppplier_Invoice_Payments Descriptor="blahblahblah">`

I want to grab the blahblahblah text portion which I do as follows using a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="suppInvoiceDesc" select="wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/@wd:Descriptor" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($suppInvoiceDesc,':')" />
```

This grabs the text part that I would like.

Now my question is, can I do the all of this in one line?

I am going to add in padding so that all the text fields are of certain widths, and I would like to avoid creating a variable for each field and then doing the substring separately.

Comment: Have you tried putting the attribute selector into the `substring-after` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just substitute the variable reference with the expression used to compute the variable, using parentheses if necessary. So

```
<xsl:variable name="suppInvoiceDesc" select="wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/@wd:Descriptor" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($suppInvoiceDesc,':')" />
```

becomes

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/wd:Supplier_Invoice_Payments/@wd:Descriptor,':')" />
```

The only time you can't play this trick is if the context changes, for example if the variable reference were inside a predicate.